# socket.setTimeout() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, keep-alive

I trying to implement http server based on net module.
I need to implement keep-alive in it, so I call to `sock.setKeepAlive(true)` and then `sock.setTimeout` to close the socket after 2 sec timeout.
Here Is my code:

```
var server = net.createServer({ allowHalfOpen: false},socketListener);

function start(port){
    server.listen(port,'localhost');
}

function socketListener(sock){
    sock.setEncoding("utf8");
    sock.setKeepAlive(true);
    sock.setTimeout(2000,function(){
        sock.end("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
    });
    sock.on("data",responser.responserCreator(sock,httpParser,baseDir,stat));
}
```

But when I open a browser and to `http://localhost:1234/profile.html` for the first time it works fine, but if I make a refresh after 2 sec it throws an exception -

> Error: This socket has been ended by the other party at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:274:12)

If I comment the timeout everthing works fine.
What wrong in my code?

Comment: Enabling *TCP* keepalive and setting an unrealistically read timeout doesn't constitute implementing HTTP keepalive. They are completely different things. HTTP keepalive requires keeping connections *open* and sending the appropriate headers to say so.

Comment: Tnx for answer.So I need to delete timeout on socket and only add `Connection: Keep-Alive` header + send `Connection: close` on timeout(2 sec - it is by spec. I received)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add `sock.destroy()` inside the timeout function right after `sock.end()`

Comment: What is the reason for calling `destroy()` after `end()` as opposed to just `destroy()`?